# Roots of polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the roots of the equation $x^3-5x^2+8x-6=0$ are alpha,beta and gamma. How to find the $\sum \alpha^2 \beta^2$ ?

Can't anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Do you mean $\alpha^2 \beta^2+\alpha^2 \gamma^2+\beta^2 \gamma^2$ ?

Comment: @lhf yup. How to simplify it?

Comment: Let $f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$. Multiplying this out will tell you values for $\alpha\beta\gamma$, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$, and $\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha$. That should be sufficient for you to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to find $\alpha^2 \beta^2+\alpha^2 \gamma^2+\beta^2 \gamma^2$, then consider this:
$$
(\alpha \beta+\alpha \gamma+\beta \gamma)^2 = (\alpha^2 \beta^2+\alpha^2 \gamma^2+\beta^2 \gamma^2) + 2\alpha \beta \gamma(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)
$$
and use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).